# Symfony : Custom repository function returns a non-object result

Tags: symfony

Here is the content of my custom repository function for my entity `Feed`.

```
return $this->createQueryBuilder('f')
->select('f, COUNT(s)')
->leftJoin('f.subscriptions','s')
->groupBy('f')
->having('f.inCatalog = TRUE')
->orHaving('COUNT(s) > 0');
->getQuery()->getResult();
```

I want to get every feed with at least one subscription in my catalog, then browse it in a `foreach loop` but it returns this :

```
FatalErrorException: Error: Call to a member function getId() on a non-object in * line *
```

Any idea how to solve this problem ?
I saw you could do, for example, `$feed[0]->getId()` but I want an object, not an array.
Some topics are similar but I didn't find any good answer.

EDIT : Well, i think i found the answer to my own question...

To get what i want, i need to remove the COUNT() in the select. I don't want it and it is only needed in the HAVING.

This looks to be working :

```
return $this->createQueryBuilder('f')
->leftJoin('f.subscriptions','s')
->groupBy('f')
->having('f.inCatalog = TRUE')
->orHaving('COUNT(s) > 0');
->getQuery()->getResult();
```

Now the result returns an array of objects as i wanted.
Thanks to the people who answered.

Comment: Did you check if the query returns any results by var_dump the result? Also it will be good help if you provide you entity mapping for us

Comment: If i use var_dump, the browser usually crashes (too big). I will edit the post to add the mapping.

Comment: Did you also try `->select('COUNT(s.id)')` ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use at least a primary key in your `select`, `f.id` in this case I guess and group by this id

Answer (score 0):

Try it with partial...

```
$qb->select('partial f.{id, subscriptions}, count(s.id)');
```

the results might be given back in an array, so you can try access it

```
{{ feed[0][0]->getId() }}
```

see my similar question:
[How can I select count(field) and still get an object with createQueryBuilder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22574618/how-can-i-select-countfield-and-still-get-an-object-with-createquerybuilder)